# Добавить текст в поле textarea

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть обычное поле для ввода текста:

```
<textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="70">'.$row[descr].'</textarea>
```

В поле ставятся некоторые html теги. Можно как то, через JavaScript например добавить кнопку, которая, при нажатии будет добавлять к набранному тексту тег `<br>`?

Comment: наверно, не java, а javascript. это как «город» и «огород», только несколько букв совпадают.

Comment: @Андрей, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector('.addBr').onclick = function () {
  document.querySelector('textarea').value = document.querySelector('textarea').value + '<br>'
};
```

```html
<textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="70">
    asdasd
    asdasd
    asdasd
    asdasd
</textarea>

<button class='addBr' type="button">add br</button>
```

Comment: Не понимаю, здесь в примере код выполняется, а на своей тестовой странице ничего не происходит.

Comment: выводить пробовал через console.log() значение и еще вопрос у тебя textarea один?

Answer (score 0):

В свое время тоже была такая задача, сделать простенький редактор

В итоге я решил задачу через добавление [простой панельки инструментов](https://corpocrat.com/2008/08/15/free-wysiwyg-bbcode-editor-in-javascript/)

Демо там 404 сейчас, но исходник с примеров в архиве качаются нормально

Опишу суть работы. При создании панелька инструментов привязывается к определенной textarea, а при нажатии кнопок из textarea вынимаются данные - положение курсора, выделение и так далее. После того, как данные удалось вынуть, предпринимаются действия - добавить тег в позицию курсора, обрамить выделение тегами или что-то еще

Вы можете подключить готовый BBEditor, убрать лишние кнопки, добавить свои кнопки для своих тегов, поменять поведение и так далее. Можно стилизовать и поменять тему/кнопки/картинки

А можно просто посмотреть исходник и скопировать только то что вам нужно:

```
function doAddTags(tag1, tag2, obj) {
    var postfix = "";
    var suffix = "";

    if (tag1 == "[blockquote]" || tag1 == "[pre]") {
        suffix = postfix = "\r\n";
    }

    textarea = document.getElementById(obj);
    if (document.selection) {// Code for IE
        textarea.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        //alert(sel.text);
        sel.text = tag1 + suffix + sel.text + postfix + tag2;
    } else {// Code for Mozilla Firefox
        var len = textarea.value.length;
        var start = textarea.selectionStart;
        var end = textarea.selectionEnd;

        var scrollTop = textarea.scrollTop;
        var scrollLeft = textarea.scrollLeft;

        var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
        //alert(sel);
        var rep = tag1 + suffix + sel + postfix + tag2;
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, start) + rep + textarea.value.substring(end, len);
        textarea.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        textarea.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
    }
}
```

Это функция, обрамляющая выделение двумя тегами, например `[b]...[/b]`. Лаконично и кратко

В вашем случае добавить `<br>` по клику можно примерно вот так:

```js
function brClick(textarea_id) {
  var tag1 = '';
  var tag2 = '<br>';
  var suffix = '';
  var postfix = '';

  textarea = document.getElementById(textarea_id);
  if (document.selection) { // Code for IE
    textarea.focus();
    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.text = tag1 + suffix + sel.text + postfix + tag2;
  } else {
    var len = textarea.value.length;
    var start = textarea.selectionStart;
    var end = textarea.selectionEnd;

    var scrollTop = textarea.scrollTop;
    var scrollLeft = textarea.scrollLeft;

    var sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end);
    var rep = tag1 + suffix + sel + postfix + tag2;
    textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, start) + rep + textarea.value.substring(end, len);
    textarea.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    textarea.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea_id" rows="6" width="98%">
Some text here
with br or without
so, the end
</textarea>
<p>
  <button onclick="brClick('textarea_id')">Add <br> tag to textarea</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так правильно:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function()
{
 var ta = document.querySelector('textarea');
 ta.value += '\n';
 ta.focus(); // чтобы не терялся focus после нажатия на кнопку
};
```

```html
<button type="button">Новая строка</button><br>
<textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="50">Первая строка</textarea>
```

В `textarea` тег `<br>` должен быть заменён на `\n`, поскольку иначе переноса строки не будет, а будет добавляться просто `<br>`, но ни как перенос строки, а как текст.